# Ошибка в ungettext

Tags: python, django

Уже час бьюсь, не могу понять, где ошибка.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ungettext as _

# ...

    def description(self):
        return _(' %(_amount)s %(_items)s') % \
            { '_amount': self.items, '_items': _('item', 'items', self.items) }
```

Метод ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно вот так:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.translation import ungettext as __

# ...

    def description(self):
        return _(' %(_amount)s %(_items)s') % \
            { '_amount': self.items, '_items': __('item', 'items', self.items) }
```